# Vertical list view is not as smooth as it should be using Lazy column of Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am a beginner in Jetpack compose. I try to implement a vertical list view in my app :

```
@Composable
fun VerticalListView(posters: List<Poster>, callback : OnClickListener) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(
            items = posters,
            itemContent = { item ->
                VerticalListItem(item = item, callback)
                ListItemDivider()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

When I scroll in the listView, it is not as smooth as it should be, and it stuck in the middle of scroll. Here I display the content in the main fragment :

```
    @Composable
    private fun Content(viewState: ViewState<List<Poster>>) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = {
                        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)) {
                            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.disney))
                        }
                    },
                    elevation = 8.dp,
                )
            },
            content = {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    when (viewState) {
                        is ViewState.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
                        is ViewState.Success ->
                            VerticalListView(viewState.data, OnClickListener { poster ->
                                val destination = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDetailFragment(poster)
                                findNavController().navigate(destination)
                            })
                        is ViewState.Error ->
                            ErrorView(message = viewState.message, viewModel::refresh)
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

And here is implementation of ViewModel stateFlow :

```
private val _stateFlow = MutableStateFlow<ViewState<List<Poster>>>(ViewState.Loading)
    val stateFlow: StateFlow<ViewState<List<Poster>>>
        get() = _stateFlow

    init {
        refresh()
    }

    fun refresh() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.result.collect {
                _stateFlow.tryEmit(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

You can find the full source code here : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/SampleCompose

Do you think why lazy column is not as smooth as it should be in my implementation?

**ADDENDA**

Maybe it is related to image loading in the app :

```
@Composable
fun loadPicture(url: String): MutableState<Bitmap?> {

    val bitmapState: MutableState<Bitmap?> = remember { mutableStateOf(null) }

    Glide.with(LocalContext.current)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) { }
            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Bitmap,
                transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
            ) {
                bitmapState.value = resource
            }
        })

    return bitmapState
}
```

And here is my Image :

```
@Composable
fun ImageView(url: String, height: Dp) {
    val imageModifier = Modifier
        .height(height)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)

    val image = loadPicture(url = url).value
    image?.let { img ->
        Image(
            bitmap = img.asImageBitmap(),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = imageModifier,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to test in a release (preferably with R8 enabled) build, not on a debug build. Performance on release is significantly better than on debug.

Comment: @Francesc, I tried but I saw the same thing. I guess it could be related to image loading in my app. Can you check the Addenda section in the question.

Comment: I would suggest you use Coil for remote image loading  as it will load in a background thread.

Comment: @Francesc I used Coil-compose and it solved the problem, but image loading seems pretty slow in Coil-compose.

Comment: You can explore several options on Coil and you can also warm-up the cache if you know the images you are going to need.

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/mvarnagiris/compose-glide-image/blob/master/compose-glide-image/src/main/java/com/koduok/compose/glideimage/GlideImage.kt) Glide wrapper implementation

Comment: Glide is pretty much the best in matters of performance and speed based on the benchmarks I've seen but Google is pushing Coil as it's the only image loading library that uses Coroutines. As far as I know Coil is as fast as Picassa which is not that great.